# Writing "blocking" code in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Everything in nodejs is non-blocking which is nice, but how would I go about making function alls that have to be one after the other without having a huge nested list of callbacks?

Comment: Node.js is meant for non-blocking code. You're going against the flow and defeating the very purpose it exists by trying to make it blocking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't **have to** nest your callbacks.

There are many patterns in writing asynchronous code.

For instance, this matrioska-nested-style...

```
database.find('foo', function (err, data) {
  database.update('foo', 'bar', function (err, data) {
    database.delete('bar', function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

... can be rewritten in a cleaner (but more verbose) way:

```
var onDelete = function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    },

    onUpdate = function (err, data) {
      database.delete('bar', onDelete);
    },

    onFind = function (err, data) {
      database.update('foo', 'bar', onUpdate);
    };

database.find('foo', onFind);
```

Another option is using a module to abstract serial and parallel execution of callbacks.

Comment: The pattern that I've been successful with is using a Promise Library, such as BlueBird:https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification and the pattern I use (like masylum says) is the one suggested under "Rookie Mistake 1" in the following article: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 8):

[Use](http://thechangelog.com/post/516202796/step-control-flow-the-node-js-way) [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step).

It's "a simple control-flow library for node.JS that makes parallel execution, serial execution, and error handling painless".

Comment: +1 It IS an answer, albeit succinct, though I might point to the entire list of control flow libraries https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-async-flow

Comment: @Chetan: A link is fine, but you should not need to click on a link to know what you mean. A succinct description of the link should be here

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added a description in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually want to do is find out why your operations are blocking and recode them so they are non-blocking. Remove the dependencies on each other. You need to change the way you're thinking about non-blocking IO.

Using a library to allow you to run this type code in a synchronous blocking manner is just a poor crutch.

You will be significantly better off learning how to write non blocking code in node.js because that's what it is designed to do.

Answer (score 2):

The [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) is a particularly good solution - using it results in much cleaner asynchronous code, with much shallower nesting. You can get it via:

```
npm install async --save
```

Especially take a look at:

- **async.series**: this lets you set up a list of functions to run one after another - where each in the list runs only after the one before it has completed. However, other code (outside the defined series) can run without blocking.
- **async.series**: this is similar to async.series, except each function on the list passes its result to the next in the list, with the final result passed to a callback defined at the end.

However, all of [async's control flow-specific methods](https://github.com/caolan/async#control-flow-1) are very helpful for avoiding huge nested callback lists.

Also, if it helps, [here's a jsFiddle I put together](http://jsfiddle.net/andfaulkner/4hve9r20/) when learning the library, containing a set of examples, including one for async.waterfall & another for async.series (open the console to see what it's doing).

Answer (score 1):

```
use ES6 async and await method's for writing blocking code
====================================================================
Ex: 
  async function fName(){
   lat firstResult=await task1;
   let secondResult= await task2
}

function task1(){
   //write your logic and after finishing your task return result as a PROMISE
return new Promise((reslove,reject)=>{
   // write logic hear after reslove(success) or reject(error)
})
}

function task2(){
   //write your logic and after finishing your task return result as a PROMISE
return new Promise((reslove,reject)=>{
   // write logic hear after reslove(success) or reject(error)
})
};
```